# How tracking users and purchases using Shopify API?

Tags: shopify

We are developing a unique platform for eCommerce sites, and we are now creating a shopify extension.
Our problem is this: we have ids for each visitor (visit id and visitor id) . In addition, we are tracking orders / purchases and every order must be associated with these ids. 
The ids are tracked and assigned using cookies.
Our experience & statistics shows that ~20% of the users disable the 3rd party cookies. Therefore, we save the cookies on both domains: our domain and the hosting site domain (website that is based on shopify platform).
In shopify, when you are moving from the site to the checkout, you are moving to shopify domain, and therefore we cannot track after the visitor unless the 3rd party cookies are enabled. So, we might loose ~20% of the purchases made in shopify, since the ids are not associated with the order.

Is there any way to add these ids to the cart, and retrive them in the conversion tracking code?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you build your App correctly there is an easy way to do this. Every cart generates a cookie as you know, allowing you to track the customer during their spelunking through a Shopify session. Once the customer hits checkout and checks out, you lose that. The saving grace is that you get the same ID as the cookie in the final order, which you get in your App. So now you can close the loop, and connect the client side cookie to the order itself, therefore you lose nothing.

I am not sure how you missed that simple thing?

Comment: So your suggestion is to correlate between my internal id and shopify's id, and make this correlation in my server side. right?

Comment: Your internal ID is just your own housekeeping exercise and has zip to do with processing data. Shopify issues a client-side ID you get on the final order too. So therefore you can wrap a pretty little bow on all your data.